# How to call document with lang="en" to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I'm trying to create a conditional styling on javascript by calling this line found before the head and body tag:

```
<html class="js" lang="en">
```

I need to create a condition if the lang === "en" will display an image I hid with english content on it. I also have lang="de" which is another image with deutsch content hidden too.

Both images are linked in an `<a>` tag and if the site is in english, the english image will appear once clicked, if it's in german, the deutsch image will appear once the link is clicked. I had the link in modal to pop up the image once clicked.

Here's the image html code:

```
<a>
    <p><img> English Image FAQs</p>
    <p><img> Deutsch Image FAQs</p>
</a>
```

I hope I'm making sense. Thank you

Comment: Does it have to be done in JavaScript? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang exists.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about lang selector. I got it fixed with the help of @jns code too. Thanks everyone CBroe and Drago96

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this, I guess this is what you want:

```js
const setLang = (lang)=> document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute("lang", lang);
setLang(navigator.language.slice(0,2))
```

```css
.en, .de {
  display: none;
}
html[lang="en"] .en {
  display: block;
}

html[lang="de"] .de {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a>
    <p class="en"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=en"> English Image FAQs</p>
    <p class="de"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=de"> Deutsch Image FAQs</p>
</a>

<a onclick="setLang('de')">de</a>
<a onclick="setLang('en')">en</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

CBroe suggestion in the commens is better, making use of the :lang selector.

---

You don't really need javascript to do this, since css is enough. You could do a little change to your markup, adding a class for the two different paragraphs (or maybe an helper class):

```
<a>
    <p class="english-only"><img> English Image FAQs</p>
    <p class="deutsch-only"><img> Deutsch Image FAQs</p>
</a>
```

Then from css you could say:

```
html:not([lang=en]) .english-only {
    display: none;
}

html:not([lang=de]) .deutsch-only {
    display: none;
}
```